Approximate identity and positive element condition
Let $u_\lambda$ be an approximate identity of a $C^*$-algebra $A$.
If $A$ has an identity $I$, a nonzero selfadjoint element $a$ is positive if and only if
\begin{equation}
\left\|I - \frac{a}{\|a\|}\right\| \leq 1.
\end{equation}
Then, are there similar conditions with respect to approximate identities?, such as
\begin{equation}
\left\|u_\lambda - \frac{a}{\|a\|}\right\| \leq 1.
\end{equation}

One condition is that
\begin{equation}
\left\|u_\lambda - \frac{a}{\|a\|}\right\| \leq 1.
\end{equation}
for all sufficiently large $\lambda$. To check this, if $\varphi$ is a state then $\varphi(u_\lambda)\to1$. Hence
$$
\left|1 - \varphi\Big(\frac{a}{\|a\|}\Big)\right\|
=\lim_\lambda\left|\varphi\left(u_\lambda - \frac{a}{\|a\|}\right)\right|
\leq\left\|u_\lambda - \frac{a}{\|a\|}\right\|\leq
1.
$$
This implies that $\varphi(a)\geq0$ for all states $\varphi$, and hence $a\geq0$.

Thank you very much!

Glad I could help!
